# How do I stop Chromium from changing tab when a page is loaded?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, browser

I use Chromium as my daily browser. Most of the time, I keep several tabs open and I follow this pattern:

- open a link that ends up in a new tab
- switch to a different tab while the page is loading to do something else

This kind of "human parallelism" is useful to reduce wasted time. However, this recent update disrupted my workflow:

```
andrea@farore /v/l/apt> zgrep chromium history.log.1.gz 
Upgrade: chromium-browser:amd64 (50.0.2661.102-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.1237, 51.0.2704.79-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.1242), chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:amd64 (50.0.2661.102-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.1237, 51.0.2704.79-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.1242), chromium-browser-l10n:amd64 (50.0.2661.102-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.1237, 51.0.2704.79-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.1242)
```

Now, **every time** I open a tab and then switch to a previous one, Chromium focuses back the newly opened tab as soon as it finishes fully loading/rendering the page.

This occurs also if I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click a link to open it *directly in a background tab* without switching to it.

For instance, if I were loading a tab and then writing this question, parts of my message would end up in the address bar of the new tab after a while because Chromium would have focused it.

How do I stop this behavior?

## Demo

[image: screencast]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out the problem was caused by an extension, in this case RiteTag.

The extension somehow makes a page to "blink" as soon as it's open and this leads Chromium to focus on the tab which gets shown as a result.

The solution to this problem is to find out which extension is conflicting with Chromium and disabling (or uninstalling) it.